# ionic 3 Inject NavController/Tabs into app.component.ts or tabs.ts

Tags: angular, ionic3

When i try to use Tabs module i get error:

```js
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Nav, App, MenuController, Tabs } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = ContactPage;

  tabbar: any;
  constructor(private appGlobal:AppGlobal, tabs:Tabs) {
  //Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Tabs!
    console.log('tabs ', tabs); // namely need to get current tab instance
  }
```

namely I need to get current tab instance.
NavController gives same error
app.component.ts gives same error
Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not the way `Tabs` work in Ionic. It is not a service you can inject in your class. You should have a look at the ionic [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/) for the Tabs component.

To get the currently selected tab you can use the [getSelected()](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/#getSelected) method which returns the currently active [Tab](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tab/):

Your template:

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And the corresponding class:

```
export class TabsPage {
  @ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.tabRef.select(2);
    console.log(this.tabRef.getSelected());
  }
}
```

Comment: this.tabRef.getSelected() returns NULL

Comment: Did you select a Tab before?

Comment: No, it loads at first

Comment: Did you add `<ion-tabs selectedIndex="0">` in your template or `this.tabRef.select(0)` in your class before accessing `getSelected()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get tab page this way.

In the tabs page get your tabs element in ViewChild like this:

```
@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;
```

After that attempt to get selected tab:

```
this.nav.getActive().component.tabRef.getSelected().root
```

This will give you the page

Comment: if you about Nav from 'ionic-angular' I am getting undefined : constructor(nav: Nav) {
console.log(nav.getActive());

Comment: but just console.log(nav); returns data

Comment: sry   import ViewChild "import { Component, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';"